# Scaling a sprite by pressing buttons going too quickly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scale

When I press left arrow I want to scale down a sprite and when I press right arrow I want to scale up the sprite. I made this code and it works but it goes insanely fast. If I press the button for 1 sec it scales up to 1 million times. What am I doing wrong? `scalingSpeed` is like 0.0001 and still it goes crazy fast.

```
if(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
    this.transform.localScale -= new Vector3 (this.transform.localScale.x - scalingSpeed, this.transform.localScale.y - scalingSpeed, 0);
} else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
    this.transform.localScale += new Vector3 (this.transform.localScale.x - scalingSpeed, this.transform.localScale.y - scalingSpeed, 0);
}
```

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to your problem? If the answers given don't provide what you need, please add a comment here or edit your question to clarify. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your scaling code doesn't linearly alter the `localScale` of the sprite - it's practically exponential! Consider the following:

```
localScale += new Vector3 (localScale.x - scalingSpeed, localScale.y - scalingSpeed, 0);
```

translates to:

```
localScale = localScale + new Vector3 (localScale.x - scalingSpeed, localScale.y - scalingSpeed, 0);
```

Which means that every frame, you're not adding a vector-equivalent value of `scalingSpeed` to the `localScale` - you're adding the *difference* between the `localScale` and `scalingSpeed` to the `localScale`, which is much, much bigger (almost doubling `localScale` every frame).

Using both `+=` and altering each component of `localScale` is redundant. My suggestion? Don't subtract `scalingSpeed` from each component of `localScale` - instead, multiply it with `Vector3.one` and add/subtract that instead:

```
if(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
    this.transform.localScale -= Vector3.one * scalingSpeed;
} else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
    this.transform.localScale += Vector3.one * scalingSpeed;
}
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it will fire on every GetKey event.  That's more than once per key press, as the docs say ["Think auto fire"](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html).  You need to limit it to once for each key press.

Look at [Input.GetKeyDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html)